# Showing a matrix is nilpotent if its charateristic polynomial is $t^n$ mod ${\rm nil}(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. How to prove the following:

> If $\chi_A(t) \equiv t^n \bmod\operatorname{nil}(R)$ then $A \in M_n(R)$ is nilpotent.

Note $\chi_A$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

This is in reference to "Strongly clean matrix rings over commutative local rings" (Borooah)

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: I've tried to understand the proof of this theorem. And I quite understand but there are some steps that I want to discuss. This question I use to provoke discussion.

I'm sorry.

Comment: That is okay, it is just that you should then point out the points you want to discuss in the question.

Comment: I hope that $u \equiv v \mod \operatorname{nil}\left(R\right)$ means $u \equiv v \mod \operatorname{nil}\left(R\right)\cdot R\left[T\right]$ here when $u$ and $v$ are polynomials in $R\left[T\right]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\chi_A(T)\in R[T]$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A\in M_n(R)$. Say $\chi_A(T)\equiv T^n\bmod{\rm nil}(R)$.

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem we know $\chi_A(A)=0$. But $\chi_A(A)=A^n+f(A)$ where $f(\cdot)$ is some polynomial with nilpotent coefficients from ${\rm nil}(R)$, by the hypothesis. Sums and products of nilpotent elements are nilpotent in commutative ring, so since all the scalars involved in $f(A)$ are nilpotent, so too must $f(A)$ be. Thus $A^n=-f(A)$ is nilpotent. If a power of something is nilpotent, then it is too.